# regex - Uppercase letters followed by any utf-8 lowercase characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regex which is valid if it starts with IJ followed by any lowercase letters in utf-8.

```
private static String pattern = "^\\u0049\\u004A(\\p{Ll})*";
System.out.println(Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher("IJP").find()); // true
```

I am using this regex but it doesn't seem to work. For "IJP" it should not match as P is uppercase.

Comment: All you missed is `$`. Use anchors to make sure you match the entire string regardless of the regex method you are using (`find()` or `matches()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern should be:

```
final String pattern = "^\\u0049\\u004A\\p{Ll}*$";
```

Note placement of `$` in the end to make it 0 or more lowercase characters before end. Note that I have removed unnecessary group around `\p{Ll}`.

**Code Demo:**

```
jshell> String pattern = "^\\u0049\\u004A\\p{Ll}*$";
pattern ==> "^\\u0049\\u004A\\p{Ll}*$"

jshell> Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher("IJP").find();
$6 ==> false
```

Answer (score 0):

`\\u0049` is a rather obtuse way of writing `I`, don't you think? Why not just... write `pattern = "^IJ\\p{Ll}"`?

IJP does match though. Think about it. You're asking for an I, then a J, then 0 or more lowercase letters. Which is right there: An I, a J, and 0 lowercase letters.

Either use `matches()` instead of `find()` (which asks: Does the ENTIRE string match the regexp, vs. 'is there some substring that does') or, as you've already thrown the `^` in there, toss a `$` at the end to match.

Comment: To allow only if it's IJ, I used "^IJ\\p{Ll}*$"